# Loading specific div from jquery $GET requested page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, get, target

I have something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="lol">LOL</a>        
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#lol').click(function(){ 
  $.get("<?php echo $host.'/index.php'?>", 
  { page: "topobjekt", index: "<?php echo $l;?>", pages: "<?php echo $pg+1;?>" },
  function(data){
           $('#primary_content').html(data);
                });
        });
```

Is it possible to load specific div(for instance #secondary_content) from my GET requested php page and load it into #primary_content target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not modify your PHP script to handle the AJAX request specifically? You will save wasted bandwidth loading a whole page when you know all you need is one div.

Add a get variable and check for this to determine context.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$('#primary_content').html(data);
```

To this:

```
$('#primary_content').html(data.find("#secondary_content"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the load method, which can specify elements in the target page:

```
$('#primary_content').load('<?php echo $host.'/index.php'?> #secondary_content');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like

```
$('#primary_content').html(data.find('#theDivId'));
```